# Solve dependencies on docker-compose

Tags: java, docker-compose, spring-cloud, microservices, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring boot microservice connecting to a Spring configuration service to get the config, but apparently, the service cannot start after the config server it's completely up and running, otherwise it will never be able to connect again (?)

Here's the error I see in the service's console when I run the docker-compose file:

> 2016-04-07 14:25:51.305  WARN 1 --- [           main]
>   c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate
>   PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for
>   "http://configserver:8888/myservice/default": Connection refused;
>   nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
discovery:
  image:discovery-service
  ports:
   - "8761:8761"
configserver:
  image:config-service
  ports:
   - "8888:8888"
  links:
   - discovery
myservice:
  image:my-service
  ports:
   - "9006:9006"
  links:
   - discovery
   - configserver
```

And this is the service bootstrap.yml config:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myservice
  cloud:
    enabled: true
    config:
      uri: http://configserver:8888
encrypt:
  failOnError: false
```

Once both services are running and registered on Eureka (discovery), I try to call `/refresh` on `myservice` but it keeps failing and returning the same error.

If I restart the docker instance it connects without issues.

Does that mean I have to keep the config server running continuously to be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the client app to be more robust if the config server is not ready yet when it starts. there's a section in the [user guide](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#config-client-retry). TL;DR include spring-retry and set `spring.cloud.config.failFast=true`.

Comment: That makes sense, however I still don't understand why it doesn't connect after the config server is available and why do I need to restart MyService to make it work, shouldn't it pick it up once it's up and running?

Comment: Maybe you didn't read the user guide carefully enough. It will connect eventually as long as the retry parameters are liberal enough.